# How to configure Spring-sesssion Custom Cookie by xml

Tags: spring-session

sorry for my poor english, my current config like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.session.web.http.DefaultCookieSerializer">
    <property name="cookieName" value="test_sessionid"></property>
    <property name="cookiePath" value="/"></property>
    <!-- <property name="domainName" value="example.com"></property> -->
    <property name="domainNamePattern" value="^.+?\\.(\\w+\\.[a-z]+)$"></property>
</bean>
```

i want to custom a domain,it is working well while i configured the `domainName` property.but when i configure the `domainNamePattern` as above,it just working on `localhost` and ip address,but no 

        `www.example.com
        test.example.com`

tks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are not using a valid Regular Expression (the expression is escaped for Java String but you are using XML). The expression will not match any of the domains so it will always use the current domain. Try the following instead:

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.session.web.http.DefaultCookieSerializer">
    <property name="cookieName" value="test_sessionid"></property>
    <property name="cookiePath" value="/"></property>
    <!-- <property name="domainName" value="example.com"></property> -->
    <property name="domainNamePattern" value="^.+?\.(\w+\.[a-z]+)$"></property>
</bean>
```